# Can all players change roles with "New Assigment"?

Tags: pandemic, pandemic-on-the-brink

In Pandemic On The Brink, the wording for the "New Assignment" special event card says:

> Any player (including the current player) may discard their current Role card and select a new one from the unused ones in the box.

Our reading of this card is that **all** players may chose to change their role cards when this card is played. Is this correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only **one** player can change their role. The game's designer Tom Lehmann answered this in a [thread](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/494697/clarification-of-the-new-assignment-special-event) on BGG:

> Matt's and my intent is that any *one* player may change their role.